# How i can create an update button in my local (on computer) php program to update database online

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is how can i create such an update button in php in my locally hosted php application which when clicked updates records in an online database ?

Comment: show what u have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using codeigniter

Step 1 : create the button in local application

Step 2 : Create a link when that button is clicked and attach the data to that link. This link should call the controller and it's function in Step 4. 
and then attach some data as an argument to the function

Step 3 : Go to the online server and create a Controller

Step 4 : create a public function in the controller and make it so that it 
can receive the data you have sent through your local server link in Step 2.

Step 5 : update the database

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot